# Swift 3 Core Data Forced Downcasting to NSManagedObject Subclass

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

So I've been learning and working with `CoreData`, and I've been very frustrated by the following problem. When I start my App, I want to fetch my `CoreData` as the custom `NSManagedObject` subclass that I've created. But the forced down casting never works. I've followed the Apple guide.

My data is the following. Below is the custom `NSManagedObject` subclass:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
@objc(StudentUniversityData)

class UniversityData: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var universityName:String
    @NSManaged var chineseName:String
    @NSManaged var bottomReadingPercentile:NSNumber
    @NSManaged var bottomMathPercentile:NSNumber
    @NSManaged var topReadingPercentile:NSNumber
    @NSManaged var topMathPercentile:NSNumber
}
```

Here is the code I've created:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let studentUniversityFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "StudentUniversityData")
    studentUniversityFetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false    
    do {
        let studentUniversityResults = try managedContext.fetch(studentUniversityFetchRequest)
        savedUniversities = studentUniversityResults as! [UniversityData] // the problem is HERE; this part never works
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print ("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

[Here is one picture of my `CoreData` entity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLyZo.png)

[Here is another picture of my `CoreData` entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CyEp.png)

No matter what I try to do, the `savedUniversities` property is always nil.

Also, I read that having multiple targets will screw up the code. So I made sure that all my classes only have one target (I took out the tests and UItests target membership). Still doesn't work.

Sorry if this isn't very clear, as I'm very tired and have worked on this problem for hours (without any progress). I've read many questions on Stack Overflow, like:

[Unable to find specific subclass of NSManagedObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076276/unable-to-find-specific-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject)

[CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613971/coredata-warning-unable-to-load-class-named)

[Core Data: Could not cast value of type 'MyType_MyType_2' to MyType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048458/core-data-could-not-cast-value-of-type-mytype-mytype-2-to-mytype)

But I'm still stuck.

Comment: are you sure about your "saveContext()"? i.e are you sure that you are saving the data? you can't fetch data that is not exist :)

Comment: It exists. When I do "po studentUniversityResults", I get "▿ 10 elements
  - 0 : <NSManagedObject: 0x6080000bc260> (entity: StudentUniversityData; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://3DD1B6C5-F53B-46AE-A3A5-D5E555472DEA/StudentUniversityData/p1> ; data: {
    bottomMathPercentile = 500;
    bottomReadingPercentile = 500;
    chineseName = "\U5927\U5b66\U4e8c";
    topMathPercentile = 750;
    topReadingPercentile = 750;
    universityName = "asdf University";
})"

Comment: These details don't add up. Since you're using `as!`, the downcasting should either succeed or cause a crash; you would not get nil as a result unless you were downcasting something that was already nil. If you were using `as?` then nil would make sense, but not with `as!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve my problem after another half-day.

What I did was rename my Core Data entity to "UniversityData". That made it match the NSManagedObject subclass "UniversityData."

Everything works after the names match.

It seems that a lot of Core Data only works if the names match *exactly* with everything in your subclasses.

Comment: Haha yup. That's how it finds it at runtime