# Swift 3 Xcode 8 not able to archive the app due to codegen coredata issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode8, tvos

This is getting disgusting as since 1 hour I am trying to archive the app to upload it to iTunesConnect but its giving error on one of my coredata auto generated files provided below, but I can see the file there. I tried all combinations to generate the files within codegen module like "Manual/None and other two" but still not able to get pass through this mindblowing irritating error.

Yesterday I was able to archive but today its not getting resolved did all steps provided [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64936) but still similar kinds of errors. Any ideas?

> error: no such file or directory:
>   '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FMCAppleTV-fbvbljepjyqcvtbphmyderhrmtmj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FMCAppleTV/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/FMCAppleTV.build/Release-appletvos/FMCAppleTV.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/FMCAppleTV/ThingMo+CoreDataProperties.swift'
>   Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: If you have found a bug with Xcode or think you may have found a bug then post on the Apple Developer forums or use one of your Technical Support Incidents (TSI): https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931137/xcode-is-looking-for-core-data-entity-names-with-dot-not-compiling/39933534#39933534. Suggested workaround which worked for me:

- remove the customization of the "Module" field of the entity, so it has the default value of "Global namespace" (in light gray text).
- change Codegen to Class Definition
- clean Project and Derived Data

Answer (score 0):

try added a new attribute to your entities, clean and rebuilt it, remove the attribute, clean and rebuilt it.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked for me:
(Please read the complete steps before judging that it is same as other solutions)

1. Just go to the xcdatamodel file
2. Select any one entity
3. In the right panel, under the "Class" section you will find the value
   for  "Codegen"
4. For me the value was "Class Definition"
5. I switched to "Manual/None"
6. Save the file by pressing "Cmd + s"
7. Switch back to "Class Definition".. again save the file by "Cmd + s"
8. Archive

Voila!!! It archived successfully.