# Cannot create NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to learn CoreData. 
I created a single entity with only one attribute and created it's **NSManagedObject** using the **Editor** menu.

But as soon as I try to build the app I am shown a Swift Compiler Error

File Structure:

[image]

Data.xcdatamodeld:
[image]

Error: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manually generating a `NSManagedObject` subclass, which has already been generated by Xcode.

Find detailed solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39933534/1457385).

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your entity(Item) -> Goto Data Model Inspector -> Under Class -> Select Codegen -> choose **Manual/None.**
2. Now Restart your XCode.

FYI check below image.

[image]

I have created simple core data app which helps you to understand basics of how to insert data, delete and update.

take a look [here](https://github.com/AshokICreate/CoreDataNoteApp).