# How to manually trigger generation of NSManagedObject subclasses in Xcode8

Tags: core-data, xcode8, ios10

I would like to use the old codegen capabilities (before Xcode 8) for core data: Therefor I am setting the Tools Versions at the File Inspector to Xcode 7.3 but no success. Using "**Editor -> CreateNSManagedObject Subclass**" still generates files *Recipe+CoreDataClass.h/m* and *Recipe+CoreDataProperties.h/m* in my example and not as expected *Recipe.h/m*

It makes no different if I am choosing "**Class Definition**" or "**Category/Extension**" at **Class -> Codegen** at the Data Model inspector.

[image]

Comment: It's just a different file name, so what difference does it make? Rename the file if you don't like the name.

Comment: With the generated code I am getting a "duplicate symbols for architecture armv7" error.

Answer (score 0):

To use the manual triggered `NSManagedObject`subclass code generation like used to in older Xcode versions (<= Xcode7), set `Codegen` to none.

You can find details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39933534/1457385).

Comment: That is what I am doing but no success I will now download the older version of Xcode (7.3) and build the classes there.

Comment: I recommend against it. How I understand your comment, you are setting Codegen to none and get duplicate symbols.  Follow the linked answer. If you have a issue afterwards, please describe the actual issue.