# Receiving error <unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory:

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Whenever I attempt to build I get this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/trevorjordy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Duelyst_Database-eiwmunfsyfyouhbystikkuvfadfh/Build/Intermediates/Duelyst Database.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Duelyst Database.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/.NewestCardsEntity+CoreDataClass.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/trevorjordy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Duelyst_Database-eiwmunfsyfyouhbystikkuvfadfh/Build/Intermediates/Duelyst Database.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Duelyst Database.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/.NewestCardsEntity+CoreDataProperties.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/trevorjordy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Duelyst_Database-eiwmunfsyfyouhbystikkuvfadfh/Build/Intermediates/Duelyst Database.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Duelyst Database.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/.SetsEntity+CoreDataClass.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/trevorjordy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Duelyst_Database-eiwmunfsyfyouhbystikkuvfadfh/Build/Intermediates/Duelyst Database.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Duelyst Database.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/.SetsEntity+CoreDataProperties.swift'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

This has gotten quite frustrating since I have tried all other solutions to no avail. I can confirm that these files are in my compile sources as well as in the same folder as all other swift files. These files were generated by core data. Even when I deleted any trace of these files, I still manage to get this error. 
So far I have tried : restarting and cleaning everything, deleting derived data, deleting the files causing the problem completely from my computer and from Xcode so that it would not try to look for it, ensuring that everything is part of compile sources and located in the same place, compiling on simulator as well as real iPhone

Comment: Tried cleaning derived data folder contents? Also post what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Mr.Bista how would I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8#answer-40278559, do not delete the folder, but delete the contents of it.

Comment: @Mr.Bista just tried, didn't work.

Comment: @Mr.Bista added what I've tried to the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Just had to swap the drop down in .xcdatamodeld file that appears when you click on an entity and look at the "class" section in the right panel. needs to be set to Manual/None when you generate the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide whether you are triggering `NSManagedObject` subclass generation manually or let Xcode do this for you.

You can finde more detailed information [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39933534/1457385).